# floating label in phpmaker

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to create a custom template for my phpmaker project, I tried every possible solution to change the default CSS for labels but I cannot get input: focus selects input when it gets focus and Selector input: not(: focus): valid select input if valid input did not focus. Please suggest some ways to solve this issue

```
<div id="r_tennam" class="col-sm">
  <div class="floating-group">
    <label id="elh_tender_tennam" for="x_tennam" class="col-sm col-form-label ew-label"><?php echo $tender_add->tennam->caption() ?><?php echo $tender_add->tennam->Required ? $Language->phrase("FieldRequiredIndicator") : "" ?></label>
       <div <?php echo $tender_add->tennam->cellAttributes() ?>>
        <span id="el_tender_tennam">
               <input type="text" data-table="tender" data-field="x_tennam" name="x_tennam" id="x_tennam" maxlength="200" placeholder=" " value="<?php echo $tender_add->tennam->EditValue ?>"<?php echo $tender_add->tennam->editAttributes() ?>>
          </span>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Tip: If your server is configured properly you can use a short for echo. For example: `<?=$variable?>`

Comment: it is not a server issue I'm trying to add CSS